# How to Copy Image File from Gallery to another folder programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-contentprovider, android-file

I want to pick image from gallery and copy it in to other folder in SDCard.

Code to Pick Image from Gallery

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY);
```

I get `content://media/external/images/media/681` this URI onActivityResult.

I want to copy the image,

Form `path ="content://media/external/images/media/681`

To `path = "file:///mnt/sdcard/sharedresources/` this path of sdcard in Android.

How to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
OutputStream out;
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
            File createDir = new File(root+"Folder Name"+File.separator);
            if(!createDir.exists()) {
                createDir.mkdir();
            }
            File file = new File(root + "Folder Name" + File.separator +"Name of File");
            file.createNewFile();
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);                       

        out.write(data);
        out.close();
```

Hope it will help u

Comment: out.write(data); what is "data" ??

Comment: data will be the bytes[] of image which u have to convert from image

Comment: Is this the recommend way or the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 36):

Thanks to all ... Working Code is Here..

```
     private OnClickListener photoAlbumListener = new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sharedresources/"+HelperFunctions.getDateTimeForFileName()+".png";
            uriImagePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath));
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriImagePath);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY);

          }
      };

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch(requestCode){
               
              
                 case 22:
                        Log.d("onActivityResult","uriImagePath Gallary :"+data.getData().toString());
                        Intent intentGallary = new Intent(mContext, ShareInfoActivity.class);
                        intentGallary.putExtra(IMAGE_DATA, uriImagePath);
                        intentGallary.putExtra(TYPE, "photo");
                        File f = new File(imagepath);
                        if (!f.exists())
                        {
                            try {
                                f.createNewFile();
                                copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())), f);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        startActivity(intentGallary);
                        finish();
                 break;
                 
                 
                }
              }
           
           
        
          
        
   }

   private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
            if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
                return;
            }
            
            FileChannel source = null;
                FileChannel destination = null;
                source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
                destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
                if (destination != null && source != null) {
                    destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                }
                if (source != null) {
                    source.close();
                }
                if (destination != null) {
                    destination.close();
                }
            
            
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    
       String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: what is shareinfoactivity ?

Comment: Hi, can you post what is the significance of HelperFunctions.getDateTimeForFileName() in the code above?

Answer (score 5):

one solution can be,

1) read bytes from inputStream of the picked file.

> > i get "content://media/external/images/media/681" this URI onActivityResult. 
> >     You can get the file name by querying this Uri u got. get inputStream of it. read it into byte[].

here you go/

Uri u = Uri.Parse("content://media/external/images/media/681");

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(u, null, null, null, null);
there is a column name "_data" which will return you the filename, from filename you can create inputstream,

you can now read this input stream

```
         byte data=new byte[fis.available()];
          fis.read(data);
```

So you have data(byte array) with images byte

2) create a file on to sdcard, and write with byte[] taken in step one.

```
       File file=new File(fileOnSD.getAbsolutePath() +"your foldername", fileName);
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        fout.write(data);
```

as fileName you already have from the query method, use same here.

Comment: The URi.Parse is very useful. So you can just save the URi as a String and later parse it into a URi whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Was reading [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/), here they are talking about four ways to copy files in Java,
so relevant for android as well. 
Though author concludes that using 'channel' as used in @Prashant's answer are the best way, you may even explore other ways.

(I have tried first two, and both of them work find)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have upvoted the answer by @AAnkit, I borrowed and went ahead to modify some items. He mentions to use `Cursor` but without proper illustration it can be confusing to newbies.

I think this is simpler than the most voted answer.

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath = "";


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


                   /*Then I proceed to select from gallery and when its done selecting it calls back the onActivityResult where I do some magic*/


private void snapOrSelectPicture() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(takePictureIntent, "SELECT FILE"), 1001);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        try {
            /*data.getDataString() contains your path="content://media/external/images/media/681 */

            Uri u = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(u, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            File doc = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data")));
            File dnote = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dnote, false);
            fout.write(Files.toByteArray(doc));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy image files to any other folder directory using Content Resolver from this function

```
fun copyImageFileToMediaStore(
    context: Context,
    sourceFilePath: String,
    destinationFolder: File
) {
    val sourceFile = File(sourceFilePath)
    val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(sourceFilePath)
    val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
    val fileName = sourceFile.name
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(sourceFile)
    val resolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

    // Check if a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
    val selection =
        "${MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME} = ? AND ${MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH} = ? AND ${MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA} = ?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
        fileName,
        "${destinationFolder.path}/",
        destinationFolder.absolutePath + File.separator + fileName
    )
    val cursor = resolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )
    if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
        // File already exists in the MediaStore, do not insert it again
        cursor.close()
        return
    }

    // File does not exist in the MediaStore, insert it
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, destinationFolder.parent)
        put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            destinationFolder.absolutePath + File.separator + fileName
        )
    }
    var outputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    var uri: Uri? = null
    try {
        val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values)
        if (uri == null) {
            throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.")
        }
        outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri) as FileOutputStream?
        if (outputStream == null) {
            throw IOException("Failed to get output stream.")
        }
        val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
        var read: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
        outputStream.flush()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        uri?.let { resolver.delete(it, null, null) }
        uri = null
    } finally {
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream?.close()
    }
}
```

Call this function like this

```
    val destinationFolder = File("/storage/emulted/0/DCIM/foldername")
    val sourceFilePath = "/storage/emulted/0/DCIM/anyOtherFolder/abcd.jpeg"
    copyImageFileToMediaStore(requireContext(), sourceFilePath, destinationFolder)
```